# Is the Completeness of $X$ really necessary here?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

From an exercise in Kreyszig's Functional Analysis, it is stated that

> Let $X$ be a Banach Space and $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ such that the sequence $(f(x_n))$ is bounded $\forall f\in X'$, show that $(\|x_n\|)$ is bounded.

I attempted to prove it by letting $g_n\in X''$ be the canonical image of $x_n$ and invoked the Uniform Boundedness Theorem to show that the sequence $(\|g_n\|)$ is bounded. Since $\|g_n\|=\|x_n\|$, the sequence $(\|x_n\|)$ is bounded so the theorem is proved.

However, I noticed that nowhere in the proof did I once use the fact that $X$ is complete. The closest thing I used is the completeness of $X'$ but $X'$ is always a Banach Space regardless of $X$ so I am at lose.

So, is my proof correct? If it's not, then how could I use the completeness of $X$ to fix it? Thank you in advance.

**Edit**: It appears that $X$ being a Banach Space is really not necessary after all. Anyway, can anyone think of a way to prove it using the fact that $X$ is complete?

Comment: After going through the theorems needed to prove this, I think you might be right. I don't think you actually need that $X$ is complete.

Comment: Banach Steinhaus requires the domain to be complete. It is a Baire category argument.

Comment: But I used the theorem on $X'$, not $X$, which is always complete.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22965/bounded-and-weakly-bounded-sets-in-top-vector-spaces.

Comment: Another way to see this: The dual spaces of a (possibly incomplete) space $X$ and its completion are the same (up to canonical identifications), since each bounded linear function on $X$ is uniformly continuous and thus extends to the completion. Thus, if you consider $x_n \in X \subset \overline{X}$, you have a complete space and the assumption also holds in this larger space. This is often a nice method to extend results known only for complete spaces to incomplete ones (or to check that completeness is not necessary as in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The result holds in every locally convex space (i.e., a vector space $X$ with a family $\mathcal P$ of semi-norms: $(X,\mathcal P)$ and $(X,\sigma(X,X'))$ have the same bounded sets.

Comment: Thank you very much, before I accept this answer I'd like to ask if you might have an idea of what the author had in mind when he said that $X$ is Banach. Can you think of a way to prove the theorem by using the fact that $X$ is complete?